# How print specific duplicate value of php array

Tags: php, arrays

if i have array like that

```
$var =array('apple','egg','banana','carrot','egg','cat','dog','egg','eggplant','fish','banana');
```

i want print only all values "egg" like that

```
egg,egg,egg
```

Comment: You don't show any attempts to solve the problem yourself and we don't write your code

Comment: @Rizier123  thank brother , but i don't know what's funciton i can used it to do what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe overkill but I'm bored:

```
$word = 'egg';
$result = implode(',', preg_grep("/^$word$/", $var));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, a simple code and works well .. Thank you